# import hebrew excel file with PHP generated gibberish

Tags: php, excel, utf-8, hebrew

i have tried many things to solve this but none worked.
im trying to import an excel file(xls/xlsx/csv) which contanins hebrew characters.

Every method i tried including fopen/[php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader) and others are outputing the data in gibberish , every attempt i have made to change the encoding to UTF-8 ended with the same results,

can you offer a solution for this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, Excel has problems with UTF-8. MAybe you can store it from there in a different collation?

Comment: Excel doesn't particularly have problems with UTF-8, but typically uses locale codepages for characters. It's only when converting to other character sets through coding that problems are likely to occur when people are unfamiliar with the codepages used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing in line 635 of excel_reader2.php to `$val = htmlentities($val);` with `$val = htmlentities($val,ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');` I had the same problem in the past, and this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Excel uses a codepage value to identify the character set used in the workbook. In all probability, this is set to 862 (CP862) for OEM Hebrew. However, not all reader libraries will bother to check the codepage used (I don't know about php-excel-reader), or to convert to anything "universal", so you probably need to use iconv() or the mb_* functions to convert from CP862 to UTF-8.

```
$stringCellValue iconv ( 'CP862' , 'UTF-8' , $stringCellValue );
```